# How to derive the tezos public key from the points on the curve (SECP256K1 or P-256)

Tags: address

How can I derive Tezos public key from x,y points on the curve (either `SECP256K1` or `P-256`)?

For example, for Ethereum you can compute this using `Keccak-256` on the `[x,y]`.
The address is then obtained by taking the last 40 bytes (20 hex chars) and prefixing it with 0x for a total of 42 bytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Public keys in Tezos are stored in compressed form:

```
<1 byte prefix>|X
```

1. Prefix is b'\x02' if Y is even, b'\x03' otherwise, now you have a compressed key of 33 bytes long;
2. Add tezos prefix b'\x03\xfe\xe2V' for secp256k1, b'\x03\xb2\x8b\x7f' for p256;
3. Encode with Base58 algo with checksum.

Checkout [pytezos.crypto](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos) sources for implementation examples.

Comment: What is `Y` here? (A typo, should be X?)

Comment: X, Y are from the elliptic curve equation, for secp256k1 it's `y^2 = x^3 + 7`