# How to convert ed25519 bytes to Tezos public key

Tags: key, base58

I tried to do that by `base58` encoding `ed255191` public key bytes. Consider a following code sample:

```
const seed = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const keyPair = ed25519.MakeKeypair(seed);
const base58encoded = base58.encode(keyPair.publicKey);

console.log('ed25519 pub key bytes len: ' + keyPair.publicKey.length);
console.log('base58 pub key: ' + base58encoded);
console.log('base58 pub key len: ' + base58encoded.length);
console.log('actual key: edpktx799pgw7M4z8551URER52VcENNCSZwE9f9cst4v6h5vCrQmJE');
console.log('actual key len: ' + 'edpktx799pgw7M4z8551URER52VcENNCSZwE9f9cst4v6h5vCrQmJE'.length);
```

It prints:

```
ed25519 pub key bytes len: 32
base58 pub key: 6jRoreKb7RXAQZBuKZs7WDzsFHHrg62GkMmkXuiWqtKm
base58 pub key len: 44
actual key: edpktx799pgw7M4z8551URER52VcENNCSZwE9f9cst4v6h5vCrQmJE
actual key len: 54
```

A `base58` string that I got is 10 characters shorter than an actual Tezos public key. This, and also [that topic](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/621/how-to-derive-the-tezos-public-key-from-the-points-on-the-curve-secp256k1-or-p) suggests I need to prefix my `ed25519` data with some magical bytes before encoding it with `base58`. What are those magical bytes? Is there a documentation about that?

Thanks.

---

EDIT after Arthur B's answer:

I tried appending prefix bytes: `\013\015\037\217` to `ed25519` bytes before `base58` encoding them. Still, I got 49 characters when a real Tezos public key has 54 characters. After appending additional 4 random bytes, I got desired 54 chars and a value that starts with `edpk`. Clearly this means that prefix is correct - but where do I get remaining 4 bytes from?

---

EDIT after discussion in comments:

4 bytes were missing due to me using `base58` instead of `base58check` that has additional 4 bytes as a checksum. After using `base58check` I got 55 bytes starting with `1edpk` - so something looking like a valid public Tezos address prepended with a `1` .

Current problem is: when working with the key (specifically - computing its hash) I removed a leading `1` and got 54 characters. As a result, a library I'm using to hash a key threw an `Invalid checksum` error. Clearly, `1` is a part of `base58check` checksum. Still, if not removed the key is going to have an invalid prefix. An updated code sample looks like this:

```
const realKey = 'edpktx799pgw7M4z8551URER52VcENNCSZwE9f9cst4v6h5vCrQmJE';
const seed = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const keyPair = ed25519.MakeKeypair(seed);
const directPubKeyBytes = keyPair.publicKey;

const tezosPublicKeyPrefix = Buffer.from([13, 15, 37, 217]);
const prefixedPublicKey = Buffer.concat([tezosPublicKeyPrefix, directPubKeyBytes]);
const base58checkEncoded = base58check.encode(prefixedPublicKey).substr(1);

console.log('ed25519 pub key bytes len: ' + prefixedPublicKey.length);
console.log('base58 pub key: ' + base58checkEncoded);
console.log('base58 pub key len: ' + base58checkEncoded.length);
console.log('actual key len: ' + realKey.length);

const publicKey = new Key({ key: base58checkEncoded });
await publicKey.ready;
return publicKey.publicKeyHash();
```

It prints:

```
ed25519 pub key bytes len: 36
base58 pub key: edpkvCRxvpVG6FYAevL5Kqf4cQhaVAdyovGqrSCezHhNnav5BwjhuZ
base58 pub key len: 54
actual key len: 54
(node:12395) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid checksum
    at Object.decode (/home/kspisacki/coding/wallets/node_modules/bs58check/base.js:41:25)
    at Object.b58cdecode (/home/kspisacki/coding/wallets/node_modules/sotez/dist/node/index.js:1:12743)
    at z.<anonymous> (/home/kspisacki/coding/wallets/node_modules/sotez/dist/node/index.js:1:15122)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at o (/home/kspisacki/coding/wallets/node_modules/sotez/dist/node/index.js:1:13324)
```

Any further help with that would be greatly appreciated as I don't understand how to get this to work despite reading up A LOT on the topic ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hash a Tezos public key](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-hash-a-tezos-public-key)

Comment: Not really. I am an author of the linked question as well ;) . The linked one is about creating a hash of a public key while this one is about creating a public key itself - it's a step before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find those bytes at the bottom of this file

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_crypto/base58.ml

In your case, "\013\015\037\217"

Comment: I tried that. I `base58` encoded my 36 bytes and got 49 `base58` characters. Then apart from the prefix, I also appended 4 random bytes. I got 54 `base58` characters, starting from `edpk`. This means that prefix is clearly correct - but where do I get remaining 4 bytes to replace my random ones from?

Comment: You have to use base58Check which appends some bytes from a hash of the binary data as a checksum.

Comment: Nice. This gives me a 55 character string starting with `1edpk` . I removed leading `1`  (am I supposed to do that?) and got something that looks like a valid Tezos public key. However, after attempting to create a hash for this public key using [sotez](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sotez) I got `Error: Invalid checksum` . Does this suggest that `ed25519` bytes are wrong? Does Tezos use some custom `ed25519` variant? Implementation that I'm using to generate `ed25519` bytes is [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ed25519) .

Comment: I'm not sure about that specific module, but Sotez uses [libsodium-wrappers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsodium-wrappers) to perform its ed25519 crypto functions. You can reference [this](https://github.com/AndrewKishino/sotez/blob/master/src/crypto.ts#L163) for example.

Comment: Using `libsodium` to generate `ed25519` bytes gave me the same error. It seems that leading `1` is a part of `base58check` checksum so it should not be removed. But if not removed, the key starts with `1edpk` so, unsurprisingly I'm getting `Error: Invalid prefix` . I have no idea how to work that out O_O